# Image extension is not getting inserted in database

Tags: php, database, file-upload

I have created a code to insert image in database. But somehow it is not working. Following is my code...

```
$member_image_names = array_map( 'sanitize_file_name', $_FILES['member_image']['name'] );

    foreach ( $member_image_names as $member_image_name ) {

    $member_image_ext = strtolower( end( explode( '.', $member_image_name ) ) );

    $member_image_newname[] =  get_current_user_id() . $_SESSION['project_id'] . "_" . time() . "_" . mt_rand() . "." .$member_image_ext;

    }
```

If I give `print_r($member_image_newname);` command, I get proper output like `Array ( [0] => 21641_1531107789_1022196085.png [1] => 21641_1531107789_1879386984.png )`

but when I try to insert the same into database, only the file name gets inserted and the extension doesn't get inserted... The data inserted in database is `{"member_image":["21641_1531107789_1022196085.","21641_1531107789_1879386984."]}` I can't figure it out as to why this is happening. Plz help me out... Thanks...

Comment: check your column length

Comment: @MASh... Column length has no issue..

Comment: Then show your insert-query codes. Btw what is your column lenght?